# I don't understand how to use EnumChildWindows (win32 API)

Tags: python, winapi

I don't conceptually understand what I am supposed to do for the second parameter of `EnumChildWindows()`. The API [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows) assumes more knowledge/experience than I have (I am an amateur), and reading about callback functions did not help my understanding.  Can someone explain?

What I want to do is get a Python list of child `HWND`s, which I can then iterate through to find a particular window/control to read its text.  I have put together code that can do this second part, but that only works if I give it a hard-coded child `HWND`, which is what I am trying to automate here.

I am using Python 3.11 and the `win32api` module.

```py
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_title_text) 

child_windows = []
win32gui.EnumChildWindows(hwnd , ???, child_windows)
```

Comment: it's a function with 2 input parameters first one being a hwnd and the second one is the third parameter of your EnumChildWindows which is child_windows list

Comment: Also see [Creating, Enumerating, and Sizing Child Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-windows#creating-enumerating-and-sizing-child-windows) for a use case.

Comment: ChatGPT isn't ever going to become smart when you keep feeding it [XY Problems](https://xyproblem.info/). The solution to your undisclosed problem is [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32). Use the [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package if you need to use Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [second parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633493(v=vs.85)) to your function is a [callback function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_callback.asp)  (or, as it's known in the C/C++ world, a [function pointer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-pointer-in-c/)) that takes 2 arguments as parameters.

The first one being an `HWND`, and the second one being the other [object/pointer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-by-reference-vs-value-in-python/) that you pass as the third parameter to `EnumChildWindows()`.

If you call `EnumChildWindows()` with a NULL `HWND`, it will enumerate all windows in your system, eg:

```
EnumChildWindows(0, function_pointer, "my_value")
```

My implementation to your problem is as follows:

```
from win32gui import EnumChildWindows, GetWindowText    

my_target_hwnd = 0
def function_pointer(child_hwnd, target_name):
    global my_target_hwnd
    name = GetWindowText(child_hwnd)
    if target_name in name:
        my_target_hwnd = child_hwnd
        # Iteration stops when you return False
        return False


EnumChildWindows(0, function_pointer, "python")
if my_target_hwnd == 0:
    print("window not found")
    exit()

print(f"found window with hwnd '{my_target_hwnd}'")
```

Comment: since you are passing null as hwnd to EnumChildWindows you may also call [EnumWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows)

Comment: You provided enough code for me to grapple with what it does and I have now managed to get my desired outcome - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer by X-*-FARZA* D-_-X I have the following working code which finds all child windows of window `window_title_text` and gets the text from the child window which is of class `RichTextWndClass` (found via Spy++).

```py
top_hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_title_text) 

int_hwnd_child = 0
def function_pointer(child_hwnd, target_name):
    global int_hwnd_child
    name = win32gui.GetClassName(child_hwnd)

    if target_name in name:
        int_hwnd_child = child_hwnd
        return False

win32gui.EnumChildWindows(top_hwnd, function_pointer, "RichTextWndClass")

if int_hwnd_child == 0:
    print("Could not get RichTextClass child window hwnd")

txtlen = win32api.SendMessage(int_hwnd_child, win32con.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0)
buffer = win32gui.PyMakeBuffer(txtlen * 2 + 2)
win32api.SendMessage(int_hwnd_child, win32con.WM_GETTEXT, txtlen + 1, buffer)
window_text = buffer.tobytes().decode('utf-8')

print(window_text)
```

Comment: 1) `function_pointer` is not a good name for the callback. You should use a more meaningful name that actually describes what the function does; 2) `function_pointer()` is missing a `return True` statement when `if target_name in name` is false; 3) If you are going to stop the enumeration after finding the 1st child wndows, you may as well just use `FindWindowEx()` instead.